# Jest/React/Apollo "Cannot read property 'data' of undefined

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, react-apollo, next.js

I'm trying to get my head around testing. I've built a react/next/apollo app and I've attempted to write what I thought was a basic test but I can't get it to work. I get the following error:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'data' of undefined

  85 |     constructor(props) {
  86 |       super(props)
> 87 |       this.apollo = initApollo(props.stateApollo.apollo.data)
  88 |       this.redux = initRedux(props.stateRedux)
  89 |     }
  90 |

  at new WithData (lib/withData.js:87:73)
  at ReactShallowRenderer.render (node_modules/react-test-renderer/cjs/react-test-renderer-shallow.development.js:92:26)
  at node_modules/enzyme-adapter-react-16/build/ReactSixteenAdapter.js:287:35
  at withSetStateAllowed (node_modules/enzyme-adapter-utils/build/Utils.js:94:16)
  at Object.render (node_modules/enzyme-adapter-react-16/build/ReactSixteenAdapter.js:286:68)
  at new ShallowWrapper (node_modules/enzyme/build/ShallowWrapper.js:119:22)
  at shallow (node_modules/enzyme/build/shallow.js:19:10)
  at Object.<anonymous> (__tests__/pages/index.test.js:14:35)
```

After half a day of googling, it seems that there are two possible issues here.

1) the 'withData' HOC used by apollo is causing the shallow renderer to fail.
2) I'm missing some sort of mocking (which I don't fully understand)

The annoying thing is that I don't care about data. All I want to do is check that the page is loading the correct components.

Here is the page I'm testing:

```
// Import global 'app' component
import App from 'components/app'

// Next JS Universal Rendering toolkit
import Head from 'next/head'

// Connect to Apollo and provide data to app
import withData from 'lib/withData'

export default withData(props =>
  <App>
    <Head>
      {/* All meta information for a page should go in this component */}
      <title> Top 10 VPN </title>
    </Head>
    <p>Hello World!</p>
  </App>
)
```

and here is my test script:

```
import { shallow } from 'enzyme'
import React from 'react'
import renderer from 'react-test-renderer'

import Page from '../../pages/index.js'

describe('Index Page', () => {
  it('App is defined"', () => {
    const app = shallow(<Page stateApollo={{}} stateRedux={{}} />)
    expect(app.find('<Head>').exists()).to.equal(true)
    expect(app.find('<p>').exists()).to.equal(true)
  })
})
```

Comment: Hi Alex, I'm having similar errors. Did you ever find a solution?